# Send password from form on HTTP to php script on HTTPS

Tags: php, http, authentication, https

I have a login form situated on my home page on HTTP. I want the user to type in their username and password there (as a shortcut) and then send the variables to my login script on HTTPS.

Is it safe enough to do it this way? I really don't want the home page to run on HTTPS as well as it makes things slower without any gain really except safe variable transfer obviously, apologies if my terminology is wrong here.

Advice would be much appreciated.

// EDIT:

All passwords are hashed with SHA1 and a hashed salt [sha1(sha1(password).sha1(salt))] before inserted into the db, and this will happen on the login script on HTTPS before being authenticated against the db password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change the `action` argument from your form to the HTTPS url you want to access :

```
<form action="https://www.example.com/login.php">
```

The data will be sent to this url using the HTTPS protocol. This is assuming you use a "normal" submit button and not some custom way to send the form.

edit: As suggested in other answer, once logged, ALL the traffic must be done in HTTPS to avoid cookies theft or other problems. Only the home page **when not logged** can be securely accessed trough HTTP, once the user has entered any login information, the **subsequent traffic must be encrypted**.

Comment: This also assumes his server is configured with SSL and accepting connections on port 443.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently doing that with `action`, appreciate the feedback. I just wanted to make sure my reasoning is somewhat viable.

Comment: The question isn't about server configuration, but yeah sure, and there's also a lot of other things to take care for a working HTTPS, but I don't think this is relevant to this precise question.

Comment: I only mentioned it because his question wasn't precise, which led me to think that maybe he assumed https just magically ran alongside http anytime a webserver is running.

Comment: sending all traffic over https once logged in ludicrous. once users credentials are verified then regenerate the session id - that should circumvent anyone hijacking the initial cookie piggy backing on the submitted credentials. After that you can revert to public protocol - using secured pages for things like account detail changes.

Comment: @ToonMariner since the cookie identifying the user is sent with all connection, if you switch back to HTTP, it is really easy to hijack your session. Have a look at http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep/ . This is the reason why facebook and many others are now switching to HTTPS for **all** the pages.

Comment: yes cookies can be hijacked but sending all traffic through secure layer post login is madness - it doubles the number of requests needed to load the page. If you are logged in and want to view a page that has no secure issues then just show it. Any page that relates to the access details of the user you secure and regenerate the session...

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that if you care to encrypt username / password, you should care to encrypt the traffic as well. For example, how are you going to maintain state with a user login? Sessions? That relies on a cookie, which if someone were to intercept the session_id, they could impersonate that logged in user. So basically, if someone cares enough to intercept your usernames and passwords, they would care enough to sniff the plain text cookies, and achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. I'm going to try maintain sessions with IP address entries in my db.

Comment: Sppofing an IP isn't difficult either, and I could sniff traffic to see which IP's are hitting your server, make a guess that they are already authenticated, and connect to your server as one of those IP's. I guess it just depends on what you are protecting. If it's just a home server, it's unlikely anyone will go to the effort to intercept user credentials (that doesn't mean impossible though).

Comment: It's not user data I'm protecting rather my info, which I want to protect by them getting access to my front-end system without paying. Is this then overkill what I'm trying to achieve? And I'm a girl btw. :)

Comment: It's certainly not government information, but it's rather sensitive and we would want to protect as far as possible.

Comment: Hah sorry! That's what I get for making assumptions about programmers being guys. If it's sensitive information in any way, I would use HTTPS for all of it. I work in InfoSec and based on what you've told me, it would be fairly trivial to get into your app as an authenticated user. From there, I could likely break some things to get the server / database to spit out useful error messages that would let me compromise your whole box, and from there, your network.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the action of the form should point to https://blah.blah...

The protocol then dictates that the browser initiate a connection , swap encyptions keys , encrypt data and finally send.

The fact you are on a public page posting to a secure page is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you, that's precisely what I wanted to hear.